# Wordpress Shortcode in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to create a shortcode to display blogs using this code in the functions.php file, I copied it from the blog template.

When I use the shortcode in a wordpress post, it isn't displaying the blogs as I want them to. Is it because of the php tags inside of the html?

```
function wpse_143641_homebox_shortcode( $atts ) {
  return <<<HOMEBOX
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
            <div class="container blog">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-2">

                    <?php
                    $temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;
                    $wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('posts_per_page=6' . '&paged='.$paged);
                    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

                        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                            <div class="entry-meta">
                                <?php neue_posted_on(); ?> by <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_author(); ?></a>
                            </div><!-- .entry-meta -->

                            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        </article>

                    <?php endwhile; ?>


                    <?php if ($paged > 1) { ?>

                    <nav id="nav-posts">
                        <div class="prev"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Previous Posts'); ?></div>
                        <div class="next"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Posts &raquo;'); ?></div>
                    </nav>

                    <?php } else { ?>

                    <nav id="nav-posts">
                        <div class="prev"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Previous Posts'); ?></div>
                    </nav>

                    <?php } ?>

                    </div> <!-- /.col-md-8 -->
                </div> <!-- /.row -->

                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

            </div> <!-- /.container -->
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

HOMEBOX;
}
add_shortcode( 'homebox', 'wpse_143641_homebox_shortcode' );
```

Comment: I noticed when I do paste the shortcode into a post, it comments out the PHP tags in the HTML.

Comment: Shouldn't your call to wp_reset_postdata(); be just after the <?php endwhile; ?>

Comment: Is $paged a global?

Comment: @magenta I'm not sure, not really familiar with PHP at all. :(

Comment: I would read the source of this code again as it looks funny to me. In particular $paged is not defined and wp_reset_postdata() looks out of place.

Comment: @magenta What I'm trying to do is take the blog part of the website and put it on the home page. The code works when I make a template, but I'm trying to make it into a shortcode.

Comment: The environment of code running inside a template and the environment of code running inside a shortcode is different. Please read https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query.

Comment: When run in a template the code is the main query. When run in a shortcode the code is different from the main query. Since, both queries share globals you need to be careful about restoring the state of the main query.

Answer (score 0):

please try below code. it will help you

```
function wpse_143641_homebox_shortcode( $atts ) {
?>
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
        <div class="container blog">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-2">

                <?php
                global $wp_query;
                $temp = $wp_query;
                if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); } else if ( get_query_var('page') ) {$paged = get_query_var('page'); } else {$paged = 1; }
                $wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('posts_per_page=6' . '&paged='.$paged);
                while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

                    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                        <div class="entry-meta">
                            <?php //neue_posted_on(); ?> by <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_author(); ?></a>
                        </div><!-- .entry-meta -->

                        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </article>

                <?php endwhile; ?>



                <nav id="nav-posts">
                    <div class="prev"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Previous Posts'); ?></div>
                    <div class="next"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Posts &raquo;'); ?></div>
                </nav>

                <?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp; ?>

                </div> <!-- /.col-md-8 -->
            </div> <!-- /.row -->

            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

        </div> <!-- /.container -->
    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
<?php
}
add_shortcode( 'homebox', 'wpse_143641_homebox_shortcode' );
```